# Using with RIA and WCF without RIA, which one is suggested?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

what is the advantages/disadvantages of using RIA against WCF without RIA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advantages:

- Validation; you write validation once, and it works on both client and server sides
- Simplified code; WCF is encapsulated, so you call RIA-based services synchronously, don't have to build proxies, etc.
- Tight integration with data controls

Disadvantages:

- Lots of generated code in your projects
- XAML markup can get very dense, even for simple stuff
- (as of the CTP; haven't started working with the beta yet) no integration with Blend

RIA services is still a "work in progress" so it's too early to tell just how it will play out. I'm looking forward to playing with it a lot over the Christmas holidays.

Answer (score 0):

The only disadvantages I can see are:

- You introduce a new dependency on your project.
- The learning curve.
- It's still a beta.

That is, the usuarl disadvantages on using a third-party library.

As for the advantages, I recommend to [install it](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=76BB3A07-3846-4564-B0C3-27972BCAABCE&displaylang=en) and taking a look at the documentation of the library itself.